# Basic Variable Loundess Audio Amplifier

Tags: audio, potentiometer, gain, variable

I am a beginner, looking to make an extremely basic variable loudness (gain) audio amplifier. I have a general idea of how a class A amplifier works, but I am not sure how to make one variable. [image]

This is the basic circuit I'm working off. I believe that a potentiometer needs to be added in place of the resistor (R1) to change the loudness of the signal, but I am not completely sure. I understand that an amplifier like this will never sound great, I just want it to work even a little bit.

Comment: Can you edit the post and ask a specific question?

Comment: What's better?  learn how good design works or attempt a cheap and dirty one that you don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual volume control arrangement is something like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTYfg4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT:**

Although you didn't ask, you should not place the speaker directly in the collector lead - the DC current may damage the speaker.  Instead, put a resistor in the collector lead and use a capacitor to couple the signal from the transistor collector to the speaker.  This is still a very poor circuit to drive a low impedance speaker.

Comment: Your circuit applies a DC voltage to the speaker that an amplifier NEVER does because the DC causes the coil and cone to move to one side hitting the magnet structure.

Comment: @Audioguru: True - but I was just answering the volume control question, and otherwise just following the OP's circuit.

Comment: ok but posting a circuit that is just going to sound horrendous or even damage the speaker is not OK. At least add a blocking cap.